# How to render video to plane/face-of-mesh in evee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Let's take the generic example of the preloaded cube, how do I apply video to each of the faces? I prefer the non-node method of doing this.

As well explain how to display it in the 3d viewport if it won't automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your mesh UV map as for a simple image texture.

Use a material (say 'principled BSDF) and set is color input to 'image texture'.

Choose the video you want from the disk.

In the movie part, set the wanted option (start frame, frames, etc.).

[image]

Turn on viewport shading, and play the animation.

[image]

Comment: Does evee have like a materials or texture view like 2.79 cycles does? It crashes blender if I go full render view with or without lighting for alot of stuff including this.

Comment: No crash here for this simple setting. So I don't know. Blender 2.8 is still in pre-release so could have bugs for some reasons.